# How to download all files shared in a google drive folder?

Tags: wget, download, google-drive

None of the other solutions answers are working.

I have hundreds of images and some subfolders in a publicly shared google drive folder.

I want to download all of them.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a job for one of many clients that you find for cloud storage; there's literally dozens. A popular one is rclone

Comment: [Here's a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25033499/17417427) how to download files or folders